# Customize Standard Chatter Component

Tags: lightning-apps

A previous developer added custom inner tabs in the Standard Chatter Component. When I go into Lightning App Builder for my app, there doesn't appear to be a way to remove the inner tabs. I want to remove Quick Tasks, Rx Sync, and a few others that are in More. How is it done?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are Quick Actions. They're defined in the Page Layout for this object/record type/profile combination, and you'll find them in the Mobile & Lightning Experience Actions section.

Drag the Quick Tasks, Rx Sync, and other tabs you no longer want out of that section to remove them.

Comment: Thanks again David. 